# missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword

Tags: sql, plsql, compiler-errors

I've got a little problem with the missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword error in a oracle database, but i can not figure out what my mistake is.

I have already checked several answers in here and other sites but can't figure out what i did wrong in my trigger statement.

The purpose of this trigger is to log all changes done in the flight table of our database (Insert update delete) and also log the changed values into the `logging_table`, so far I took out all other parts as it throws the error way before i get to the `IF`.

It tells me the Error: ORA-04071: missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword

Edited Code is set in ***Comments***:

```
  create table logging_table (
    changeType varchar2(20),  
    changeTime timestamp, 
    changeUser varchar2(20),
    changeStatement varchar2(200));

create table flug2412 as select * from flug;

create or replace trigger change_flights
BEFORE insert /*or update or delete */ on flug2412 for each row
declare

  v_type varchar2(20);
  v_time timestamp;
  v_user varchar2(20); /*v_user varchar2(30) := user;*/
  v_statement varchar2(200);

begin 
  IF INSERTING THEN 
    v_type := 'I'; /*v_type := 'Insert';*/
    v_time := timestamp; 
    /* Select user into v_user from dual;*/ 
    v_statement := to_char('Insert'|| /*:new.v_type*/ 
                          || ', FlugzeugID: ' || :new.flugzeugid 
                          || ', GateID: ' || :new.gateid 
                          || ', Abflughafen: ' || :new.flughafen_abflug
                          || ', Destinations Flughafen: ' || :new.flughafen_destination
                          || ', Abflugzeit: ' || :new.systimestamp /*:new.abflugzeit*/
                          || ', Flugnummer: ' || :new.flugnummer
                          || ', Flugdauer: ' || :new.dauer);
    insert into logging_table(v_type, v_time, v_user, v_statement);  
  END IF; 
end;
/
```

Comment: remove the `declare` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#BABBJHHG

Comment: Hey, i just changed it to `as`, but it still comes up with the same error message :/

Comment: Just one mistake, you have missed the trigger name in below statement : create or replace trigger TRIGGER_NAME

Comment: Trigger name is missing.

Comment: oh damn :0 didnt notice at all ! thank you :) 

Okay thank you ! now it almost works just have to settle my mistakes inside now.  apparently i can't bind my `:new.v_type` and `:new.systimestamp`. 

Do I even need to add a variable at this point ? - As it seems to me to be a big mistake from me because i already mentioned that it is a `Insert-Type change` . Is there any posibility to bind that String into the variable ? 

And moreover how can i put a new `systimestamp` into my table inside the trigger ?

Comment: `:new.systimestamp` would refer to a column in the `flug2412` table named `systimestamp`. I'm guessing there isn't one.

Comment: btw you don't need to `select user into v_user from dual;` as you could just declare it as `v_user varchar2(30) := user;` in the `declare` section. Except it's surely a constant not a variable, and in any case you could just refer to `user` in the trigger body and not declare anything. In fact, why doesn't `logging_table` have a default so you don't need to keep coding it? (Same goes for `v_time`.)

Comment: Ahh i think i now understand the problem of my thoughts. I need to refer to column name and not to what fills it. 

so in my case the colum name is `abflugzeit` so i will need to refer to it with `:new.abflugzeit` if i get it right.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Thank you for the hint! yes in my case here it definitely is a constant as i can't have any other user than myself in my connection :) 

Okay I didn't know that it was possible to just refer to `user` :)

Comment: Also [`to_char()`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions002.htm) is a conversion function for turning either a datetime or a number into a character string,  but your concatenated expression is already a string and so doesn't need any converting.

Comment: I thought i would need it so could just transfer all the values (Strings + numbers + datetime) from my `insert` into my `logging_table` so that the whole string is put into that table.